# Can not create gradle project with IntelliJ on Windows

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea

When I attempt to make a Gradle java project with IntelliJ I get this error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Initialization script 'C:\Users\ARCHIE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\wrapper_init2.gradle' line: 6

* What went wrong:
Could not compile initialization script 'C:\Users\ARCHIE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\wrapper_init2.gradle'.
> startup failed:
  initialization script 'C:\Users\ARCHIE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\wrapper_init2.gradle': 6: unexpected char: '\' @ line 6, column 61.
     le('C:\\Users\\Archie O'Connor\\AppData\
                                   ^

  1 error


* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.groovy.scripts.ScriptCompilationException: Could not compile initialization script 'C:\Users\ARCHIE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\wrapper_init2.gradle'.
Caused by: org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
initialization script 'C:\Users\ARCHIE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\wrapper_init2.gradle': 6: unexpected char: '\' @ line 6, column 61.
   le('C:\\Users\\Archie O'Connor\\AppData\
                                 ^

1 error
```

This still happens when I change the project directory, even outside my user folder. Gradle projects only work if I generate it with IntelliJ in macos and reimport it in windows.

Comment: Is it because of the apostrophe (`'`) in your username?

Comment: @dnault yeah it was due the (') in my name.

Comment: There is an existing issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-177302